# How to pass data from an customized helper to a view with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created an helper class to show values coming from a database.

**Helper**

```
if (!function_exists('items')){
function show_items($item)    {


$ci = get_instance();
$sql = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE items = '$item'";
$result = $ci->db->query($sql);
return $result->row();
}

}
```

In the view I use the function like this:

```
echo show_items($item)->main_image);
```

The echo above shows obviously only the first row of main_image.

My goal is to show all the rows of the selected $item.

If I change the helper like this

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM table WHERE items = '$item'";
$result = $ci->db->query($sql);
return $result->result();// first option
return $result->result_array();//second option
}

}
```

how can I loop the result in the view using for istance a foreach?

Comment: I noticed one thing... In your helper, shouldn't your function_exists be checking for the function show_items and not items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your helper code with

```
$query->result_array():
```

//this is your view code

```
 <?php $result = show_items($item); ?>// call helper

// DATA RECALL FROM THE HELPER
    <?php foreach($result as $data): ?>
       <?php echo $data['main_image']; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```